# How to implement Vector Quantisation using KMeans on a PGM Image

Tags: java, k-means

Require to do, 
Vector Quantisation using KMeans on a PGM file (or image compression)
Images are a PMG file with b = block size, k = num of times, t = iterations, -g = inital centroids

image is something like 
126 131 128 126 
129 130 127 128 
130 123 132 128 
131 124 131 129 
.
.
129

Algorithm 1 K-means algorithm
Require: Input data X = {x1; x2;... xN}, number of clusters K where K <= N, initial
guesses for the centroids Y = {y1; y2;..yK}, maximum number of iterations T.

> for t = 1; 2; .... T do
>    for i = 1; 2; .... N do
>      Find the centroid from the current set Y that is closest to xi.
>      Assign xi to its closest centroid.
>    end for
>    for j = 1; 2; .... K do
>      Update yj as the average of the vectors that are assigned to yj .
>    end for
>    end for

After K-means, we reduce the original data into a list of K prototype vectors Y, as
well as for each vector in X the index of the prototype vector it is closest to, i.e.,
X = {x1; x2; .. xN} -> Y = {y1; y2; .. yK},L = {l1; l2; .... lN};
where each li in an integer between 1 and K indicating to which prototype vector xi is
closest. Instead of X, only Y and L are stored or transmitted. For example, using b = 4
and K = 256, for a 420x300-pixel image (123 KB uncompressed) we need to store
X = 256 x {16 byte} + Y = 7875{byte}s ~ 12 KB:
storage for y         storage for L

To reconstruct the image from the compressed data, for each b x b block we simply
ll it with the derasterised prototype vector that is closest to the block (recall that
each block corresponds to a vector xi which has an index value Li

**What i'm asking is i have absolutely no idea what does it mean to Assign update yj as the average of the vectors and how to reconstruct the image, can anyone explain to me.
And yes this is homework, but i'm really lost, if anyone can point me in the right direction.**

Answer (score 0):

So initially you just make some random guesses for what the centroids (y's) should be. Let's say you want 3 clusters and initially your guess for centroids Y = {126, 128, 130}. After each iteration of putting every point in the cluster with the closest centroid, calculate the Y's again. So if your centroid y1 (initially 126 in this example) gets X's {126, 126, 127}, your new Y1 is the average of those 3 points (126.33). And similarly for y2 and y3.